# How Doctrine create an entity without call __construct method when fetch from repository?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, entity, fetch

I wrote next code in constructor:

```
public function __construct()
{
    die('creating entity');
}
```

When I create instance of entity with `new` operator like:

```
$entity = new Entity();
```

I see the `creating entity` text.

But when I get entity from repo:

```
$em->getRepository('AcmeDemoBundle:Entity')->find(1)
```

Doctrine create an object of entity without calling `__construct()` method and I don't see the `creating entity` text.

Can anybody explain how Doctrine creating an object when loading them from repository?

Comment: The miracle of Reflection: http://us3.php.net/manual/en/class.reflection.php

Comment: @Cerad Thanks, can you also get link to Doctrine code with this functionality?

Comment: Looks like you found it.

Comment: @Cerad Yes, thanks for advise with Reflection class

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To create an instance without invoking constructor available with [ReflectionClass::newInstanceWithoutConstructor](http://php.net/manual/ru/reflectionclass.newinstancewithoutconstructor.php)

Doctrine create instances of mapped entities without invoking constructor in [Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadataInfo::newInstance()](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/blob/400acad53355f24137e18d5cd55ccf6ff828cfbe/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/ClassMetadataInfo.php#L908)

Comment: Why new instance of Entity is created without constructor?
What is wrong with creating Entity with constructor in this case?

Comment: @PawełBrzoski I think because the entities already created and located in database. Therefore no need to create them again, need softly load them only. For Doctrine, creating new entity with constructor is means that it's a new entity, that not exists in database, but must be persisted in it.

Comment: Many thanks, for your reply. Your answer explains a lot, I think, It has sense.