# Doctrine2 ManyToMany bidirectionnal attribute populated by find method

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, orm

I want to create my entities from an existing database, it's an N - N relation which create articlesCategories table.

I currently have 2 entities, Article and Category, and I want to have a ManyToMany bidirectional relationship.

But when I try to get article or category with a findByXXX or findOneByXXX method, my ManyToMany attribute is **NULL** or I have an ORM Exception : **Entity 'App\Models\Article' has no field 'categories'. You can therefore not call 'findByCategories' on the entities' repository**

### Database :

Table article : idArticle, name, description, priceHT, size

Table category : idCategory, name, percentTaxe

Table articlesCategories : idArticle, idCategory

### Entities :

Category

```
/**
* @Entity
* @Table(name="category")
*/
class Category
{
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @Id
 * @Column(name="idCategory", type="integer", nullable=false)
 * @GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var string
 * @Column(name="name", type="string", length=45, nullable=false)
 */
private $name;


/**
 * @var string
 * @Column(name="percentTaxe",type="decimal", precision=10, scale=0, nullable=false)
 */
private $percentTaxe;

/*
 * Many categories have many articles
 * @ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\Models\Article", inversedBy="categories")
 * @JoinTable(name="articlesCategories",
 *  joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="idCategory", referencedColumnName="idCategory")},
 *  inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="idArticle", referencedColumnName="idArticle")}
 * )
*/
private $articles;


/*Constructor*/
public function __construct(){
    $toto = "toto";
    var_dump($toto);
    $this->articles = new ArrayCollection();
}

/***************************
    Getters / Setters
****************************/

public function getId(){
    return $this->id;
}
public function getName(){
    return $this->name;
}
public function getPercentTaxe(){
    return $this->percentTaxe;
}
public function getArticles(){
    return $this->articles;
}

/************************/

public function setId($id){
    $this->id = $id;
}
public function setName($name){
    
    $this->name = htmlspecialchars($name);  
}
public function setPercentTaxe($percentTaxe){
    $this->percentTaxe = htmlspecialchars($percentTaxe);    
}
public function setArticles(\Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection $articles)
{
    $this->articles = $articles;
}

/***************************
    Getters / Setters
****************************/

public function addArticle(App\Models\Article $article)
{
    var_dump($article);
    $article->addCategory($this); // synchronously updating inverse side
    $this->articles[] = $article;
}
```

Article

```
/**
* @Entity
* @Table(name="article")
*/
class Article
{
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @Id
 * @Column(name="idArticle", type="integer", nullable=false)
 * @GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var string
 * @Column(name="name", type="string", length=45, nullable=false)
 */
private $name;

/**
 * @var string
 * @Column(name="description",type="string", nullable=true)
 */
private $description;

/**
 * @var string
 * @Column(name="priceHT",type="decimal", precision=10, scale=3, nullable=false)
 */
private $priceHT;

/**
 * @var string
 * @Column(name="size", type="string", length=3, nullable=true)
 */
private $size;

/*
 * Many articles have many categories
 * @ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\Models\Category", inversedBy="articles")
 * @JoinTable(name="articlesCategories",
 *  joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="idArticle", referencedColumnName="idArticle")},
 *  inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="idCategory", referencedColumnName="idCategory")}
 * )
*/
private $categories;

/*Constructor*/
public function __construct(){
    echo"tata";
    $this->categories = new ArrayCollection();
    echo"tata";
}

/***************************
    Getters / Setters
****************************/

public function getId(){
    return $this->id;
}
public function getName(){
    return $this->name;
}
public function getDescription(){
    return $this->description;
}
public function getPriceHT(){
    return $this->priceHT;
}
public function getSize(){
    return $this->size;
}
public function getCategories(){
    return $this->categories;
}

/************************/

public function setId($id){
    $this->id = $id;
}
public function setName($name){
    
    $this->name = htmlspecialchars($name);  
}
public function setDescription($description){
    $this->description = htmlspecialchars($description);    
}
public function setPriceHT($priceHT){
    $this->priceHT = htmlspecialchars($priceHT);    
}
public function setSize($size){
    $this->size = htmlspecialchars($size);  
}
public function setCategories($categories){
    $this->categories = $categories;
}

/***************************
    Getters / Setters
****************************/

public function addCategory(App\Models\Category $category)
{
    $category->addArticle($this); // synchronously updating inverse side
    $this->categories[] = $category;
}

/************************/

public function hydrate($data)
{
    foreach($data as $key => $value)
    {
        // Get back the setter name which corresponds to the attribute 
        $method = 'set'.ucfirst($key);
        // if the good setter exist.
        if(methodexists($this, $method))
        {
            $this->$method($value);
        }
    }
}
}
```

### Manager

```
 /**
 * @param category : category of article we want
 * @return an array of Article object or null 
*/
public function getArticlesByCategory($categoryName)
{
    $articles = NULL;
    
    $repository = $this->getEntityManager()->getRepository("App\Models\Category");

    $category = $repository->findOneByName($categoryName);
    var_dump($category);

    if($category != NULL)
    {
        $articles = $category->getArticles();
    }
    return $articles;
}
```

And when I var_dump my $category, I have:

```
class App\Models\Category#122 (4) {
  private $id => int(2)
  private $name => string(7) "clothes"
  private $percentTaxe => string(2) "20"
  private $articles => NULL
}
```

---

I found my categories and articles are null instead of to be an empty array because of [Doctrine create instances of mapped entities without invoking constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25508069/how-doctrine-create-an-entity-without-call-construct-method-when-fetch-from-re) but I don't understand why It doesn't populate it.

I just use Doctrine2, I don't use Symfony.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you have an error at your annotations on **categories** and **articles** fields of both entities. To be valid they should start with /** not /*.Change:

```
/*
* Many categories have many articles
```

to

```
/**
* Many categories have many articles
```

Same for $categories field of Article Entity.

Also change one of the fields(articles or categories) to be the inverse side of the relation, e.g.

```
inversedBy="categories"
```

to
    mappedBy="categories"

On the other part of your question, **default EntityRepository find methods**(findBy, findOneBy) of the does not support filter by many to many relation(at least not yet). You will have to do the extra effort and use **createQueryBuilder**, e.g.:

```
$qb = $doctrine->getRepository(Article::class)->createQueryBuilder('a');

    $qb->select(
            'a',
            'cat'
        )
        ->innerJoin( 'a.categories', 'cat' )
        ->where('cat.id =1');
```

And better create your own ArticleRepository and CategoryRepository and define your find methods there. [7.8.8. Custom repositories](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/working-with-objects.html)

Comment: That was really sneeky, thank you you exactly point out how to resolve my problem. I will create a builder for advanced query, but for the moment I can do my stuff without it.